# My way of finding the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000

Tags: python

I want to find multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000 using the code below:

```
a=[]
b=[]
def multiples_of_3():
     i=1
     for i in range(330):
        m=i*3
        if(m<1000):
            a.append(m)




def multiples_of_5():
     j=1
     for j in range(330):
        k=j*5
        if(k<1000):
            b.append(k)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiples_of_3()
    multiples_of_5()

    print sum(a) + sum(b)
```

Result- 262355

Result is not right. It should be 233168 . How am I going wrong with the logic here?

Comment: You're counting e.g. 15 twice

Comment: This is a variation on FizzBuzz I hadn't seen before.

Comment: @Barmar - this is [Project Euler Problem 1](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping over the wrong ranges and adding multiples of 15 twice.

I believe that this is the smallest change to your program that makes it work:

```
a=[]
b=[]
def multiples_of_3():
     i=1
     for i in range(334):   # stops at 1 less than the value passed to `range`
        m=i*3
        if(m<1000):
            a.append(m)

def multiples_of_5():
     j=1
     for j in range(330):   # could change to 201 and still work
        k=j*5
        if(k<1000):
            b.append(k)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiples_of_3()
    multiples_of_5()

    print sum(set(a+b))
```

But you should probably rethink your approach.  Using global variables is generally a bad idea - looking at the call `multiples_of_3()`, there is no way to know what the subroutine is doing with those multiples; the variable `a` is not referenced anywhere, yet before the line and after the line it has two different values.  So for starters, I would turn the subroutines into pure functions - have them return the arrays instead of modifying globals.

As minor stylistic points, you also don't need to use different variable names inside the two functions, since they're all local.  You don't need to assign anything to `i` before the loops (the loop will create the variable for you), and you don't need parentheses around the condition in Python's `if` statement (the colon takes care of delimiting it):

```
def multiples_of_3():
     a = []
     for i in range(334):
        m = i * 3
        if m < 1000:
            a.append(m)
     return a

def multiples_of_5():
     a = []
     for i in range(201):
        m = i * 5
        if m < 1000:
            a.append(m)
     return a

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = multiples_of_3()
    b = multiples_of_5()

    print sum(set(a+b))
```

You could also combine the two `multiples_of` functions into a single generic one that takes a parameter telling it what to return multiples of:

```
 def multiples_of(k):
   result = []
   for i in range(1000/k+1):   
     multiple = i * k
     if multiple < 1000:
       result.append(multiple)
   return result
```

You could even turn the maximum value into an optional parameter:

```
def multiples_of(k, under=1000):
   result = []
   for i in range(under/k+1):   
     multiple = i * k
     if multiple < under:
       result.append(multiple)
   return result
```

Either way, your main part becomes this:

```
   a = multiples_of(3)
   b = multiples_of(5)
   print sum(set(a+b))
```

Finally, just as a point of reference, it is possible to do the whole thing as a one-liner.  Here I've switched from building up the list of multiples by actually doing the multiplication, to just looping over all the numbers under 1000 and testing them for divisibility by either 3 or 5:

```
print sum([n for n in range(1000) if n%3==0 or n%5==0])
```

Comment: Thanks for the insights. Could you please elaborate " Functions modifying global variables, and dependent upon the order in which they are called, is a bad idea"? I believe you are referring a[] b[] as global here?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `for j in range(330):` be `for j in range(200):` since you're using multiples of 5?

Comment: Since he tests whether the multiple is less than 1000, it doesn't matter if the limit is too high.

Comment: The actual problem is with `for i in range(330)`, because it should be `range(333)`.

Comment: Thanks guys, Now I have two list , 1)with multiple of 3 and 2) Multiple of 5. Now I have to remove the elements which are common in both lists like 15(not remove exactly but I should consider it in both the list) and find the sum.

Comment: You should create set out of sum of 2 lists.